# Can't run selenium firefox browser

Tags: linux, selenium, ubuntu

I have a problem with run selenium firefox browser.
It started after last update OS.
I use ubuntu 22.04

When I try to run test i catch this exception
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 127

I try google it, but didn't find information.

Also I have the such information in firefox log **file/snap/firefox/current/firefox.launcher: 46: exec: /snap/pycharm-community/302/usr/lib/firefox/firefox: not found**

Comment: Have you tried updating your Firefox driver to the latest version?

Comment: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service

firefox_options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
```

**# Your location binary file firefox**

```
firefox_options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/firefox"
```

**# location geckodriver**

```
s = Service("config/geckodriver") 
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=firefox_options, service=s)
```